# Alignment of instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created a test system in which I want to cut a grid into separate faces where perpendicular on each face, I create cylinder that needs to stay perpendicular when the individual faces are rotated. The part where I create the individual faces via geometry nodes is shown in the first image.
[image: first part of geometry nodes - creation of individual faces from starting grid]

The value at the bottom of the first image allows rotation of the individual faces. In the second part of the geometry nodes, I put cylinders through the center of each face, and align them perpendicular to the face. This is shown in the second image.
[image: Second part of geometry nodes - placement of cylinders perpendicular to faces.]

The problem that I am unable to fix is that, while the cylinders are perpendicular initially (see image 3), they don't stay perpendicular if rotation of the faces takes place (figures 4 and 5). Any thoughts on what else I can do apart from the rotation based on the normal to the faces?[image: starting point of image without rotation]

[image: after some rotation shown from same angle as previous image]

[image: same scene as previous image, except under a different angle that emphasises the deviation from perpendicular placement (bottom right corner)]

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost right:

[image]

(Vector input, not Rotation)